# Создание составных ключей в миграции yii2

Tags: yii2, datatable, foreign-key

Создаю миграцию:

```
 public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('script2webpage', [
        'script_id' => $this->integer(11)->unsigned()->notNull(),
        'page_id' => $this->integer(11)->unsigned()->notNull(),
    ]);

    $this->addForeignKey('FK_ITEM_SCRIPT','script2webpage', 'script_id','scripts','id');
    $this->addForeignKey('FK_ITEM_WEBPAGE','script2webpage', 'page_id','webpage','page_id');


}

public function down()
{
    $this->dropForeignKey('FK_ITEM_SCRIPT', 'script2webpage');
    $this->dropForeignKey('FK_ITEM_WEBPAGE', 'script2webpage');

    $this->dropTable('script2webpage');
}
```

При миграции ошибка

```
Error Info:
    Array
    (
        [0] => HY000
        [1] => 1005
        [2] => Can't create table 'ms.#sql-1ed4_2e' (errno: 150)
    )
```

Первый FK создается. На 2 ошибка:

```
  add foreign key FK_ITEM_WEBPAGE: script2webpage (page_id) references webpage (page_id) ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'tablename.#sql-1ed4_2e' (errno: 150)
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `script2webpage` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ITEM_WEBPAGE` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `webpage` (`page_id`)'
```

Возможно это связано с движками таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE ms.scripts (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  code text DEFAULT NULL,
  url varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  for_all tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  status tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  description text DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE ms.webpage (
  page_id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  url varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  body text DEFAULT NULL,
  layout varchar(72) DEFAULT 'main',
  menu_title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  seo_title varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  seo_description text DEFAULT NULL,
  seo_keywords text DEFAULT NULL,
  status tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (page_id)
)
ENGINE = MYISAM,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 15,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 1806,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
CHECKSUM = 0,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

ALTER TABLE ms.webpage
ADD UNIQUE INDEX url (url);
```

Как в данном случае избавиться от ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброе утро.

Причин возникновения ошибки "150" может быть несколько.

Для начала сделайте обе таблицы InnoDB.

Затем проиндексируйте те поля в родительской таблице, на которые будет ссылаться дочерняя таблица. И только после этого назначайте внешние ключи.

Например:

```
    $this->createIndex('idx-product_id', '{{%products_categories}}', 'product_id');
    $this->addForeignKey('fk-prod-cat-product_id', '{{%products_categories}}', 'product_id', '{{%products}}', 'id', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT');
```

Иногда требуется выключить проверку внешних ключей. Это можно сделать так:

```
$this->db->createCommand('SET foreign_key_checks=0')->execute();
// назначаете индексы, внешние ключи или выполняете что-то ещё.
$this->db->createCommand('SET foreign_key_checks=1')->execute();
```

Но лучше изначально правильно планировать создание таблиц, чтобы не делать такого.

По поводу ошибок, первая попавшаяся [ссылка](https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/30.html). Возможно Вам поможет.